# how to include php parameter inside js

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to include a php parameter inside my js across a language loop

The code below add a button inside the product page. When I click on the button link to the inputfield products_head_title_tag, The input is filled automatically.

the problem come from these lines :

```
 var productsName = "{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, '\" + languageId + \"')}";
 var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "languageName", 'productsName' => "productsName"])}';
  }
```

`"languageId"` must to take the value 1,2
`"languageName"` must to take the value english, french
`"productsName"` must to take the name of the product.

on `alert(questionResponse);` I have this : Give me a SEO Title in less 50 caracters about this product productsName and in function of this language languageName :

As you see productsName and languageName does not have value

But it's not the case.

When I try to insert an `alert(languageName)` or `alert(productsName)`  or `alert(languageId)`, everything works fine.

The problem is the link between the php and the js. It does not work.

Do you have any idea to resolve that ?

Thank you

my injection script :

```
     $content = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-button" data-index="0">';
          $content .= '<i class="bi-chat-square-dots" title="' . $this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title') . '"></i>';
          $content .= '</button>';
    
    $output = <<<EOD
    <script defer>
    $('[id^="products_head_title_tag"]').each(function(index) {
      var button = '{$content}';
      var newButton = $(button).attr('data-index', index);
      var inputId = $(this).attr('id'); // Récupérer l'id de l'input pour l'itération actuelle
      var regex = /(\d+)/g; // Expression régulière pour extraire l'id
      var idProductsHeadTitleTag = regex.exec(inputId)[0]; // Extraire l'id de l'input
    
      var languageName = $(this).data('language'); // Extraire la valeur de data-language
      
      if (typeof languageName !== 'undefined' && languageName !== 'undefined') { 
        var languageId = $(this).data('languageid'); // Extraire la valeur de data-languageId
     
     
        var productsName = "{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, '\" + languageId + \"')}";
        var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "languageName", 'productsName' => "productsName"])}';
      }
      
      newButton.click(function() { // Ajouter un listener pour chaque bouton
        let message = questionResponse; // Valeur envoyée à Open AI
    
        $.post("{$url}", {message: message}, function(data) {
          $("#products_head_title_tag_" + idProductsHeadTitleTag).val(data); // Remplir automatiquement l'input avec la réponse de OPEN AI pour l'itération actuelle
        });
      });
    
      $(this).append(newButton); 
    });
    </script>
    EOD;
          return $output;
```

About my product page :

```
<?php
          for ($i = 0, $n = \count($languages); $i < $n; $i++) {
            ?>
        <div class="row" id="productsSeoTitle<?php echo $i ?>">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group row" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
              <label for="<?php echo $Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?>" class="col-1 col-form-label"><?php echo $Products->getDef('text_products_page_title'); ?></label>
              <div class="col-md-4 input-group" id="products_head_title_tag<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php echo '&nbsp;' . HTML::inputField('products_head_title_tag[' . $languages[$i]['id'] . ']', SeoAdmin::getProductsSeoTitle($pInfo->products_id, $languages[$i]['id']), 'maxlength="70" size="77" id="products_head_title_tag_' . $i . '"  data-language="' . $languages[$i]['name'] . '" data-languageid="' . $languages[$i]['id'] . '"', false); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <?php
          }
        ?>
```

solution below and this

var productsName = '{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, ' + languageId + ')} ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a matter of concatenation of your JavaScript code?

In this line:

`var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "languageName", 'productsName' => "productsName"])}';`

You want 'languageName' and 'productsName' to be inserted as variables, not as a string of text, which is why `alert(questionResponse);` gives you « Give me a SEO Title in less 50 caracters about this product productsName and in function of this language languageName : ».

This might be close to what you need to do:

`var questionResponse = '{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => "' + languageName + '", 'productsName' => "' + productsName + '"])}';`

It looks like you're using a framework though, so I'm not sure how it works, you need to check how to pass the value of the variable into your string here.

Comment: Thank you very musch. I have now the languageName, about this line it does not work :
    var productsName = "{ $ProductsAdmin->getProductsName($id, '\" + languageId + \"')}";
I tried to change in function of var question but not work.

Comment: how about this way?
var questionResponse = "{$this->app->getDef('text_seo_page_title_question', ['languageName' => '" + languageName + "', 'productsName' => '" + productsName + "'])}";